# jQuery form plugin with pass dynamic data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using jquery form plugin. and this is my sample form

```
<form id='formId' action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']l?>' method='POST'>
<input type='text' name='username'/>
</form>
```

And this my Javascript

```
$('#formId').ajaxForm({
    success:function(data){
       console.log(data)
    }
})
```

In this case i want to pass another data value dynamically without implement it in HTML. For example i want to pass the password field. Is there any method to implement this option?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From [This Page](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#options-object), the `beforeSubmit` function allows you to hook into the form data submitted and inject / modify data.

It allows for 3 arguments, the form presented as an array(this means we can push into it), the form presented as a jquery Object (for serialization), and options object that you use with ajaxForm/ajaxSubmit. Working example ->

```
$('#formId').ajaxForm({
  beforeSubmit: function(formData, formObject, formOptions){
    //formData is the form array. We can push the password into the array before we submit the form.
    formData.push({
      password: //this is where you put the password you want
    });
  },
  success:function(data){
   console.log(data)
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Ohgodwhy. This is what I want. Thanks for the answer. and yes I'll definitely consider your request

Comment: I tried, but it didn't working. it return `undefined=>undefined`

Comment: use {name: 'password',value: 'password/variable'}, as answered by @mr12086

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but here is a working code snippet.
The method would be implemented in the same fashion as 'Ohgodwhy' answered

```
beforeSubmit: function(formData, formObject, formOptions){        
    formData.push(
        {name: 'password',value: 'password/variable'},
        {name: 'username',value: 'username/variable'}
    );
}
```

You need to pass the param name and param value as sets like this.